# How should I store the fetched data when I'm using async-await and useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have to fetch a player's stats based on the input given by the user, and then display it. I am having trouble storing the fetched data, using useEffect hook. Please suggest if there's a better way.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import HLTV from 'hltv';

const getPlayer = async ({ name }) => {
    HLTV.getPlayerByName({ name: name })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
}

const Search = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const onChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getPlayer(text)
}, [text])


return (
    <div>
        <form className="form">
            <input type="text"
                name="text" placeholder="Enter user" onChange={onChange} />
            <input type="Submit"
                defaultValue="search"
                className="btn btn-dark btn-block" />
        </form>

    </div>
)
```

}

export default Search

Comment: What do you mean, you're having trouble storing it? Currently, you're just console logging it out. Where do you want to store it?

Comment: My problem is that I can't store the data inside a variable, inside the useEffect. I'm console logging, just to check it's fetching or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the player using a useState hook, as follows.
You also need to bring the `getPlayer()` function inside the Search function so that you can access the player variable. Also, when you use an async function , you don't need to use `then`; you can use `await` instead.

One last thing to point out: If you're making network calls, you have to account for the possibility that they could fail, so you might want to put the call to `getPlayerByName` within a try catch.

[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/search-input-problem)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const HLTV = {
  getPlayerByName: (name) => {

    return Promise.resolve({
      name: "result:" + name,
    });
  }
};

export const Search = () => {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState({ name: 'nobody'});

  const [text, setText] = useState("initial text");

  const onChange = e => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  const getPlayer = async (name) => {
    const player = await HLTV.getPlayerByName(name);

    setPlayer(player);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPlayer(text);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <form className="form">
      <div>text: {text}</div>
      <pre>Player: {JSON.stringify(player, null, 2)}</pre>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="text"
        value={text}
        placeholder="Enter user"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <input
        type="Submit"
        defaultValue="search"
        className="btn btn-dark btn-block"
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm not facing any error with the above code, however the player data isn't getting fetched, since the id is undefined. Originally there's no way to get player using name, instead we have to use id, but the [link](https://github.com/gigobyte/HLTV) api let's us do so. Sorry for the delayed response, i was fixing few errors regarding the same.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue then. You also need to set the value into the input field: `<input type="text" value={text} name="text" placeholder="Enter user" onChange={onChange} />`

Comment: Just a side question. Is saying thank you considered unprofessional on stackoverflow ? If yes, then I appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it's encouraged. :)